# CMake "Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed"

Tags: gcc, cmake

CMake Output:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.1
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.1
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /home/bob/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
```

What does "Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed" mean - what is the cause of this error, and how is it fixed?

Comment: Are you manually specifying any flags or compiler options?  A `CFLAGS` environment variable, or an IDE setting that gets automatically passed to CMake?  I think I had something similar once.  CMake uses those flags when running compiler detections, and a misspelled flag will cause build errors.

Comment: I am trying to follow the instructions at https://wiki.qt.io/Cross-Compile_Qt_6_for_Raspberry_Pi. I run into some error regarding OpenGL during compilation, and checking the CMakeError.log can see that there are errors like "undefined reference to _dl_addr@GLIBC_PRIVATE". I inspect libc.so.6 with nm and can see that it doesn't have this (cross compiler installed from Ubuntu package manager), but the cross-compiler I download from the ARM website does, so I try to use that cross compiler instead but then get this "ABI info" error (which I currently have no idea what it means).